# How to create a pop out window when a customer clicks proceed to check out

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout

i want to make a pop out window which appears if a certain customer group is below a certain subtotal amount when they click on proceed to check out. I know how to check if the user is logged in, in a certain customer group and check if they are under a certain amount.

```
<?php if($login && Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId()==5)
    {
     if ($sub_total < 75)
    {?> <p>
     <?php echo   "As an special customer you get free delivery on all orders however we do ask if you can try to get your orders up to £75 exc VAT so we can keep our prices competitive";
    }}?></p>
```

The bit I do not how know to do is how to display a message and some options in a pop out window when the customer clicks on the proceed to check out button, and don't really know where to start.

If i am not being clear just let me know :)

Thanks if you can help

Comment: What js library do you want to use prototype or jquery? "pop out window" as in a new browser window or overlay (on top of the current cart page)?

Comment: on top of the current cart page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this code on the internet after a long itme searching. Thought i would post incase anybody else wanted to add it in

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function showForm(id){
            win = new Window({ title: "Privacy Policies", zIndex:3000, destroyOnClose: true, recenterAuto:false, resizable: false, width:300, height:300, minimizable: false, maximizable: false, draggable: false});
            win.setContent(id, false, false);
            win.showCenter();
            }
    </script>

    <div style="display:none;" id="popup_form">
     <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('checkout')->toHtml()?>
    </div>

                 <button type="button" title="Proceed to Checkout" class="button btn-proceed-checkout btn-checkout" onclick="return showForm('popup_form')" ><span><span>Proceed to Checkout</span></span></button>
```